# How do I activate NTP Server and client in windows 7 OS?

Tags: windows, ntp

How would I synchronize client's PC date and time with a server using Network Time Protocol(NTP)?

Comment: Yes, there is. But this is not a programming question, so you will not find the answer here.

Comment: thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NTP Server Side:

1)  Modify HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\Config -> AnnounceFlags=5

2)HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\W32Time\TimeProviders\NtpServer -> Enabled=1

3)  Start “Windows Time” Service

NTP Client Side

1)  Click on Date time- right bottom of the window screen

2)  Click on “Change date time Setting”

3)  Click on “Internet Time” tab

4)  Click on Change setting button

5)  In the server Drop down Edit Box Mention NTP Server IP address

6)  Click on Update Now button to sync the time with NTP Server.